# Project Not Detecting Java Filter

Tags: java, xml, servlet-filters

I'm developing a project using AspectJ where I use a filter for the http requests and responses. Basically I'm turning this project into a .jar and using this jar in a benchmark app where I perform some security tests. When I declare the filter on the benchmark app and on its web.xml it works fine, but if I put it in the project I'm developing (the jar file), then the benchmark app won't detect it... I've been told that if you use the latest version of web.xml, you don't need to declare the filter on web.xml and it should detect it automatically but it's not working. How can I get this to work?

The version I'm using in web.xml is this:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

filter class:

package main.java.filter;

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import main.java.Configuration;
import main.java.HashTableCreation;

/**
* Servlet Filter implementation class MyFilter
*/
@WebFilter("/MyService/*")
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{


/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MyFilter() {
}


/**
 * @see Filter#destroy()
 */
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("###### FILTER before NO DRIVER...");



//      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
//      
//      String loggedIn = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("login");
//      
//      if (loggedIn == null)
//      {
//          req.getRequestDispatcher("notLoggedIn.jsp").forward(request, response);;
//      }*/

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    System.out.println("###### FILTER after...");

}


/**
 * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
 */
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Initializing filter...");



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `jar` file in this case, it's simply a library. The servlet container isn't looking in your `jar` file for a `web.xml` file. That's simply not how it works. As you describe, your `web.xml` file must reference the filter explicitly otherwise the servlet container won't know to load it.

If you're trying to use annotation-based loading, per the spec, referenced in [this post](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229917?tstart=0&_sscc=t), it must be in `WEB-INF/classes` or in `WEB-INF/lib` as a `jar`.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer in advance. From what i've read in the post you mencioned it should work if the jar is within the benchmark app lib or am i wrong? " ... or if they are packaged in a jar file located in WEB-INF/lib within the application.". Im kinda confused, as i said, i've been told that with the last web.xml version it should detect the filter automatically, i mean if the benchmark app has the latest web.xml version (which it has cause i have changed it), it should automatically detect the filter within the jar file that i import to the benchmark project. Am i wrong about this?

Comment: @PedroBento I wonder if this might a servlet container-specific issue. Are you using Tomcat, Jetty or what?

Comment: @PedroBento can you post your filter class?

Comment: Hmm, I suspect the issue is path related. Are you able to insert some logging statements to see if it is getting loaded and perhaps just not getting called?

Comment: how would i do that? like with log4j? never used it before xD

Comment: one thing i forgot to mention, the benchmark detects the class name AspectJ i have inside the jar printing whatever is inside, but it wont detect the filter because it wont print the messages inside...they are on different packages but i don't think that matters...